# Searching and Extracting substring recursively with RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, substring

I'm wondering if there is a RegEx pattern to solve my problem.

I'm getting strings like:
"Running script A23jddie392.sql", 
"Skipped script ew223.sql", 
"Script 2234ffss321.sql has an error" 
and so on.

Is it possible to extract the scriptname with RegEx? Maybe searching for the .sql and then going recursively to the first blank before the scriptname?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: /(\w+\.sql)/ Don't thank me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
    var pattern = "\\s\\w+[.]sql";
    var test = "Script 2234ffss321.sql has an error";
    var match = Regex.Match(test, pattern);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I needed :)

Comment: Its failing for matches like 'aaa.sql'

Comment: And it also false positive for 'Script b1231bbsql has an error' with match '1231bbsql'. This answer is wrong

Comment: you were right, I've updated the answer